# MySQL AJAX PHP Notification Table Layout

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am having issues finishing off my notification system on my website, where a user is notified when a post or comment is made. So far, I have 3 tables: users, posts, and notifications. When a user submits content to the posts table, for example, a notification will be generated in the `notifications` table including the timestamp, where the post was, and who did it. My question is not on coding any of this, but how my tables should be set up so that when i call the query via AJAX, the user gets a number representing the number of posts/comments they have NOT seen. How do I represent in tables that a notification has not been seen by the session user? Clearly, posts seen and unseen will differ among users, and I cannot seem to wrap my head around this. I have tried the following:

- Time stamps comparing the user's last activity and the notification activity. The notification will go away immediately after the user simply goes to any other page, not the location of the notification.
- Location of the notification versus latest page user was; Every time the user visited the page with recent activity, the notification would go away, but trivially, it would appear again after the person left

So how do I simulate the 'read/unread' status of users and their notifications? Thanks everyone.

Comment: Why would you give this a downvote? Even if you did, please explain why at least...

Comment: Its referring to mysql database outline for a successful query.

Comment: Can someone please still help out? It seems very related to me.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with the second option you gave. You just have to set the status as Read in the db when the user visits a specific page... Then the status will stay Read forever (provided you don't change it back, which doesn't seem to be logical for a notification system).

Comment: A separate table that stored whether or not the user has viewed x notification should work. If you only stored it in session, as you've pointed out, they would all of a sudden become unread (or read, depending on hour it's written) once the user gets a new session, regardless of whether or not the user has actually read notification x.

Comment: Then, will it not become 'read' for every other user? Even if they have not visited it?

Comment: @stmyd Not if the notifications are made per user. (see the column user_id in the answer NinthCrow posted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your setup I would create another table `users_notifications` or something, with the columns `id, user_id, notification_id, status, timestamp` where `user_id` and `notification_id` are the unique id's to their tables respectively and `status` is an id or enum that identifies the current status of the user with that specific notification. This would enable you to easily calculate what you need now, but also grow into more if needed.

Comment: Glad this helped... I can't vote yet though, I'm only an 11 right now :)

Comment: So every time a notification is generated, one is generated for every `user_id` which can be changed from unread to read?

Comment: I would have the system assume the user has NOT read the notification unless there is an entry in `users_notifications` table... so when the user reads the notification that's the point it will write to the `users_notifcations` table with the current time etc. Then, when you're calculating for how many notifications they have not read you can query for all notifications that don't also exist in the `users_notifications` table for the current user.

Comment: Sorry, just re-read your comment. No, you'd only need the one notification in the `notifications` table. It's the `users_notifications` table that can keep track of which users have 'read' which notifications.